# Create summary table with multiple levels

Tags: r, dplyr, tabular

I have a data that is categorized into both a high-level category and a low-level category.  The data has basic structure similar to this mock one:

```
set.seed(21)
cat <- data.frame(Level1=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6),rep("C",6)),
                   Level2=c(sample(c(1:3), 6, replace=TRUE), 
                            sample(c(4:6), 6, replace=TRUE), 
                            sample(c(7:9), 6, replace=TRUE)),
                   Type=rep(c(1,2),9),
                   Value=rnorm(18))

> table(cat$Level1,cat$Level2)

  #  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  #A 1 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
  #B 0 0 0 1 1 4 0 0 0
  #C 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 4 1
```

If possible, I want to create a table that has counts and means (or other summary) for both Level1 and Level2, in a hierarchy as follows:

```
#Level1/2    Count     Mean        SD   ...  whatever
#A             6     0.15323278
#    1         1    -0.5821507
#    2         3     0.8603706
#    3         2    -0.5397822
#B             6     0.46460457
#    4         1     1.0136847
#    5         1    -0.3521069
#    6         4     0.5315124...
```

I've tried `tabular()` from the `tables` package -- which can nicely create a table with n, mean, sd, etc. based on the higher-level grouping.  I've also tried summarization using various ways of grouping with `group_by()` etc but can't make anything work with 2 ways of grouping in the same table.

I was thinking that perhaps there's a way to do it line-by-line or (block by block) in a loop process, but I can't quite envision how this would work.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 5):

Do the summary statistics twice and add the results in one table. For example, with `data.table`.

```
require(data.table)

set.seed(21)

cat <- data.table(Level1=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6),rep("C",6)),
                  Level2=c(sample(c(1:3), 6, replace=TRUE),
                           sample(c(4:6), 6, replace=TRUE),
                           sample(c(7:9), 6, replace=TRUE)),
                  Type=rep(c(1,2),9),
                  Value=rnorm(18))
cat

table(cat$Level1, cat$Level2)

# Statistics for Level1
tab1 <- cat[, .(Count = .N, Mean = mean(Value), SD = sd(Value)),
            keyby = .(Level1)]

# Statistics for Level1 and Level2
tab2 <- cat[, .(Count = .N, Mean = mean(Value), SD = sd(Value)),
            keyby = .(Level1, Level2)]

# Add in one table
tab <- rbindlist(list(tab2, tab1), fill = TRUE)

# Sort
setorder(tab, Level1, Level2)

# Print
tab
```

Result:

```
> tab
   Level1 Level2 Count       Mean        SD
1:      A     NA     6 -0.2224609 1.1052424
2:      A      1     2 -1.4125934 1.2221462
3:      A      3     4  0.3726054 0.3487678
4:      B     NA     6  0.4125892 0.8841718
5:      B      4     2  1.0854216 0.6030156
6:      B      6     4  0.0761730 0.8538268
7:      C     NA     6 -0.2347908 0.7815174
8:      C      7     4 -0.2805626 0.6948971
9:      C      8     2 -0.1432472 1.2570046
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried aggregate():

```
    set.seed(21)

    cat <- data.table(Level1=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6),rep("C",6)),
              Level2=c(sample(c(1:3), 6, replace=TRUE),
                       sample(c(4:6), 6, replace=TRUE),
                       sample(c(7:9), 6, replace=TRUE)),
              Type=rep(c(1,2),9),
              Value=rnorm(18))

    aggregate(Value~Level1+Level2, data=cat, FUN=mean)
```

Results:

```
         Level1 Level2      Value
     1      A      1 -1.4125934
     2      A      3  0.3726054
     3      B      4  1.0854216
     4      B      6  0.0761730
     5      C      7 -0.2805626
     6      C      8 -0.1432472
```

Comment: This isn't the desired output, isn't it?